# Git ignore and unversioned local files

Tags: git, git-branch, gitignore

There are a lot of questions out there covering ignoring things in git, but none seem to work for my particular situation. I have a project that looks like this:

```
proj
|-foo/
|--project-file.txt
|-bar/
|--project-file2.txt
|-temp/
|--machine-specific-file.txt
|--machine-specific-file2.txt
```

(EDIT: added for clarity) My .gitignore file:

```
temp/
```

My project has several branches, all of which have different machine-specific files in them. My problem is this: since I'm not tracking the machine-specific files (no reason to check them in, because they're only useful here), every time I switch branches and try to open my project, the machine-specific files get overwritten. This is a problem, because it takes my software about 10 minutes to generate them - annoying when I'm switching branches 5 or 6 times a day. Is there any way to somehow keep track of the machine-specific files for each branch, without having to store them on the server?

Things I've tried:

- creating a new local branch for each branch that I need to work in, saving the machine-specific files there, and when I need to merge my work, merge it first with the original branch (simple, since it's a fast forward), and then go about merging with everything else. Problems: it works, but it's messy, and sometimes takes a while to do the first merge, due to differences in .gitignore. Maybe this is the right way to go about it? It seems like there should be a better solution.
- making submodules - I don't think I understand this process, because I keep not being able to get it to work the way I want. Since the file has to be named the same thing, in each of the folders, I don't think I'm correctly specifying where the repository I want is.

Let me know if you have any pointers! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about checking in symlinks, pointing to files in a completely ignored machine-specific directory?  Each branch would have symlinks with the same name, pointing at different targets.  Each machine would be responsible for populating the machine-specific directory with the necessary contents.

```
branch a:
temp/machine-specific-1 => ../local-files/machine-specific-1-branch-a

branch b:
temp/machine-specific-1 => ../local-files/machine-specific-1-branch-b
```

Optionally check in a directory with template files, never directly referenced, and add a bootstrap script in local-files that manually copies over the files from the template directory on a fresh checkout.

Comment: oooh. I'm liking both of these suggestions.. let me try them, and I'll report back on how they worked. Thanks!

Comment: Upon further thought: the simlink solution would work perfectly if everybody on my project understood computers well enough to make it work, or if I had access to set up their machines for them. As it is, installing git requires a 2 page, very specific document that I hand wrote, because people "don't understand the instructions" on the main git site. *sigh* Since most of them will never be switching branches, my problem is unique to me. I'll try writing a bootstrap script that, on a checkout, pulls a corresponding checkout out of another local git repo.

Comment: I ended up just using the symlink thing locally with a bootstrap script. Reasonably elegant, and by far the least amount of work!

Answer (score 0):

add `temp/` to your `.gitignore` file.

This will ignore all files in this directory. When you clone to another computer, nothing will be put in this directory (nor stored when you do a `git add .` or `git commit`)

---

To do a `submodule` follow [this link](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules). The trick to doing submodules is that you have to move all of the 'wanted' files into a separate git repository. This can be tricky if you already have the sub-dir in your current git repo but isn't impossible (clone your current tree to a temporary one, do a [`git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter`](http://palleas.com/2011/02/02/how-i-turned-a-folder-into-a-git-submodule/), push it to a public repo... this way you won't lose history!). After setting up the separate remote, you'll be able to do a `git add submodule <path to repo> <localpath>` and all will be well in the world.

Comment: assuming your mention of `I'm not tracking the machine-specific files (no reason to check them in, because they're only useful here)` means you do not care to have them tracked at all...

Comment: yes, this is true, and I'm already doing that. However, since these files get overwritten when I change branches, I'm trying to figure out a way to somehow track them locally and not globally, that doesn't require me to jump through hoops every time I switch branches.

Comment: if they are being over written when you change branches, this is telling me that they ARE in fact in your repository. I would first remove them from the repo   `git rm temp/*` then make sure the appropiate filter is in `.gitignore`. Do this across the different branches and you won't have to worry about anything being overwritten.... it will just ignore this directory... To track them locally but not globally would be to do a submodule.

Comment: Ok, so, the problem is that it's not GIT that's overwriting them, it's the software I'm using. And the problem I'm having with submodules is that since I'm constrained from tracking the address of the submodule, it still becomes a song-and-dance trying to get things checked out.

Comment: Well, technically I can track the address of the submodules, but since 90% of the users of my project won't ever change branches, and won't ever have this problem, and wouldn't even fathom that there was a solution if they did, having hanging directories that are empty and need to be filled is dangerous.